# CMMotionActivityManager doesn't detect automotive activity

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

We implemented motion detection on our application. Need to detect driving activity. We added below code for activity detection.

```
 public func startMotionTracking() {
    var motion = MotionMode.unknown.rawValue;
    if CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable() {
        motionManager.startActivityUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { (activity) in
            guard let activity = activity else {
                return
            }
            if activity.walking {
                motion = MotionMode.walking.rawValue
            }
            else if activity.running {
                motion = MotionMode.running.rawValue
            }
            else if activity.cycling {
                motion = MotionMode.cycling.rawValue
            }
            else if activity.automotive {
                motion = MotionMode.automotive.rawValue
            }
            else if activity.stationary {
                motion = MotionMode.stationary.rawValue
            }
            else if activity.unknown {
                motion = MotionMode.unknown.rawValue
            }
            self.delegate?.currentMotionMode(currentMotion: motion)
        }
    }
}
```

While Driving via bike, it still gives walking activity Instead of automotive.
I'm testing with iPhone SE(2nd Gen), 16.6 version.
Please give some suggestion to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are assuming that these `Bool`s are mutually exclusive - are you sure that is the case? Since you are checking `walking` first, even if both `walking` and `cycling` or `automotive` would be `true`, you wouldn't know, since you are handling these are exclusive paths using `if else` statements.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I printed and tested all the activity before going to first if condition. Still while driving it gives walking as true. but it detect stationary and running perfectly. only Automotive is not detected.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the phone outdated? have a check `CMMotionActivityConfidence`, which represents how likely that the state is to be correct.

Comment: @Elevo Yes. I checked the CMMotionActivityConfidence, it gives confidence as 2 (high)on driving